# Minimum CSR requirements to run Linux

Tags: riscv, riscv32

What are the minimum CSR required to run Linux on a RISC-V processor?
The privileged ISA spec does not seem to clarify this point.

Answer (score 0):

A minimum requirement for an operating system would be to be able to service exceptions: external interrupts & software exceptions.

The following two answers may shed some light on this, though will not answer specifically the question of the requirements for linux.  I don't know the additional requirements of linux, but we would be thinking about clock/timer, virtual memory, others?

- [RISC-V Interrupt Handling Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913210/risc-v-interrupt-handling-flow/61916199#61916199)
- [Risc-V: Minimum CSR requirements for simple RV32I implementation capable of leveraging GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204255/risc-v-minimum-csr-requirements-for-simple-rv32i-implementation-capable-of-leve/63206687#63206687)